# perl regex: multiple matches as variables

Tags: regex, perl, variables

I am not interested in how to use a variable in a regex search. Instead, I am curious how I can turn multiple regex matches into variables.

I have a file that looks like this:

```
>m160505_031746_42156_c100980652550000001823221307061611_s1_p0|153096|3235_13893 
Length=10658

 Score = 33.7 bits (18),  Expect = 0.19
 Identities = 18/18 (100%), Gaps = 0/18 (0%)
 Strand=Plus/Minus

Query  3     CTATTTAAACCTAATCGG  20
             ||||||||||||||||||
Sbjct  10604  CTATTTAAACCTAATCGG  10587


>m160505_031746_42156_c100980652550000001823221307061611_s1_p0|114630|20543_24727 
Length=4184

 Score = 33.7 bits (18),  Expect = 0.19
 Identities = 18/18 (100%), Gaps = 0/18 (0%)
 Strand=Plus/Plus

Query  3    CTATTTAAACCTAATCGG  20
            ||||||||||||||||||
Sbjct  85   CTATTTAAACCTAATCGG  102
```

My ultimate goal is to search this (very large) file and only extract lines that look like ">m160505_..." based on the end position of the subject match (seen as 10587 and 102 in the above example). If the end position of the subject is within 500 of the Length of the query length, or if it is within 500 absolutely, the >m... line gets printed. I realize this seems complicated, so looking at my code might help clarify things. 
This is what my code looks like so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = '/path/to/file.txt';
my $data;
{
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die;
    local $/ = undef;
    $data = <$fh>;
    close $fh;
}
my @matches = $data =~ />(m.+)\nLength=([0-9]+)\n\n Score.+\n Iden.+\n Str.+\n\nQuery.+\n.+\nSbjct  [0-9]+  [TAGC]+  ([0-9]+)/g;
foreach (@matches) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

This prints out something like the following:

```
>m160505_031746_42156_c100980652550000001823221307061611_s1_p0|153096|3235_13893
 10658 
 10587 
>m160505_031746_42156_c100980652550000001823221307061611_s1_p0|114630|20543_24727 
  4184 
  102
```

From here I need to change things so the regex matches turn into variables (flexible vairables). I would like to be able to use them in something like the following:

```
 my $mVariable = "m160505_031746_42156_c100980652550000001823221307061611_s1_p0|114630|20543_24727"; 
 my $firstnumber = 10685; 
 my $secondnumber = 10587; 
 if ($firstnumber - $secondnumber < 500 || $secondnumber < 500) { 
      print $mVariable, "\n"; 
 }
```

Thanks for your help! 
If I can clarify something please let me know.

Comment: Wouldn't do it this way. First of all, you need an array of hash structures. To accomplish that you'd use the regex like `while ( $data =~ /your regex/g ) { $href = {}; $href->mV = $1; $href->N1 = $2; $href->N2 = $3; push @ary, $href; }` or something like that. Then loop through the array making calculations. Alternatively, in the while body, just do your calcs instead of storing the info.

Comment: Another note, the regex you are using is very rigid, almost fixed form. I'd loosen that up and add firmer anchors, which would give you a higher percentage chance you won't miss matches.

Comment: "(very large) file" => read one line at a time (don't load the whole file) and anchor your pattern at the start of the line using `^`

Comment: Also, Perl's variables have duality in typing. `flexible vairables` which I suppose you mean. If you use it as a string, it will convert it to a string, same with number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's wasteful and unnecessary to read an entire file into memory; more so if it is a very large file

My solution below sets the record separator to `>` so that the file can be read one chunk at a time. The variables that you describe are extracted from the chunk, and the remainder of the loop is skipped if any of them aren't found

This program expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

local $/ = ">";

while ( <> ) {

    next unless my ($m_variable) = / ^ ( m \d+ .+ ) /x;
    next unless my ($length)     = / ^ Length=(\d+) /xm;
    next unless my ($end_pos)    = / ^ Sbjct \b .*  \b (\d+) /xm;

    if ( abs($length - $end_pos) < 500 or $end_pos < 500 ) {
        say $m_variable;
    }
}
```

#### output

```
m160505_031746_42156_c100980652550000001823221307061611_s1_p0|153096|3235_13893
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks! I would just suggest one edit to the if statement: " or $end_pos < 500)", as per the question asked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Perl stores the results of captures in special numbered variables. The first capture group is `$1`, the second is `$2`, and so on. Their values are set *every* time a regex match succeeds (whether replacement or matching).

So, in your case, you could do something like this:

```
my $string = "m160505_031746_42156_c100980652550000001823221307061611_s1_p0|114630|20543_24727";
if ($string =~ /^m(\d+)_(\d+)/) {
    if ($1 < 500 || $2 < 500) {
        do_something()
    }
}
```

Comment: That values of the capture variables are set every time a regex match *succeeds*, so you need to test the result of the match before using them. You could write `if ( $string =~ /^m(\d+)_(\d+)/ and $1 < 500 || $2 < 500 ) { ... }` but your tests don't correspond to what the OP describes.

Answer (score 0):

When matching against a pattern you could extract the $1, $2, etc... using a list. So instead of:

```
my @matches = $data =~ />(m.+)\nLength=([0-9]+)\n\n Score.+\n Iden.+\n Str.+\n\nQuery.+\n.+\nSbjct  [0-9]+  [TAGC]+  ([0-9]+)/g;
```

**you could use this**:

```
my ($m_var, $first, $second) = $data =~ />(m.+)\nLength=([0-9]+)\n\n Score.+\n Iden.+\n Str.+\n\nQuery.+\n.+\nSbjct  [0-9]+  [TAGC]+  ([0-9]+)/g;
```

Comment: Not sure but, since you set the global flag there won't the list variables get overwritten on each match ? Or maybe just the last match, I'm not sure.

Comment: The global flag was in your code. But since you are insecure about it, you can read from the docs: "match the pattern repeatedly in the string" . In the case when getting $1,$2, $3 will be the last one. Just reading your problem your code is not quite right, because you have to make the pattern match for each record (>m until next >m). But, since your question was limited to understand how to get the variables I limited answer to this part of the problem.